# Stuck on Specific Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a specific case where I somehow can't find something that suits my need. I've always been struggling when parenthesis comes in strong, and this case is a bit painful. I'm trying to collect the most of a text field to fit it in a more controlled database, and there's a few tricks I'm fumbling in.

There is ONE thing that is always the case for every row entered;

serie of character + ( + text + )

Basically, here's what it could look like:

```
1111111E (CARRIER), 2222222, 33333 (CARRIER2) 44444 (CARRIER 3)
```

My goal is to get:

```
1111111E (CARRIER)

2222222, 33333 (CARRIER2)

44444 (CARRIER 3)
```

And if I can ever manage to get a hold of commas and space to split the few like the middle one, that would be just amazing.

I'm struggling through a few REGEX tester website as I'm writing this, starting from scratch over and over again.

If some regex gurus are around, you're a welcome hand !

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried so far?  Can you post them, you might be closer than you think!  Also, what exactly are you trying to extract/match from the text?  It isn't clear in your question.

Comment: Why regex?  You can do string.split on ')'

Comment: @stark I guess i like to complicate things...
You're actually totally right. >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be RegEx you could split at

```
(?<=\))[, ]*
```

Note that as you don't want to take out the ")" you must not match it and thus the statement uses a look behind which does not work in all RegEx engines.

Answer (score -1):

```
[^\s|\,].*?\s\(.*?\)
```

With a Match All is doing the expected result. I doubt it's the most optimal regex I could type in, but it seems to be working fine.

I could try to work around the second case to wrap it up, but I think I'll take care of these case in my code.

Leaving the answer up for anybody who could be looking into something similar.